# Check if a customer already exist in another database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an e-commerce with Codeigniter + MySQL, and in my cart I need to check if a customer already is registered in my ERP, that use Firebird, if exist use CODCLI from Firebird, else $data["customer_id"].

I'm using this code bellow, but have 5 sec of delay (this is made to test but I don't know how improve it and use inner a Model (connected in Firebird DB)

```
    //Verify if customer already exist in ERP
    if ($erp_consulta["tipo"] == 'f') {
        $conexao = ibase_connect("127.0.0.1:C:/DB.FDB","SYSDBA","masterkey");
        $erp_codcliverif = "SELECT count(CODCLI) FROM CUSTOMERS_001 WHERE CNPJ = '$erp_cpf'"; // vai sair
        $consult_cliverif = ibase_query($conexao, $erp_codcliverif);
        if ($consult_cliverif != 0){
        $erp_codclisql = "SELECT CODCLI FROM CUSTOMERS_001 WHERE CNPJ = '$erp_cpf'";
        $consult_cli = ibase_query($conexao, $erp_codclisql); //vai sair
            while ($row = ibase_fetch_row($consult_cli))
            {
                    foreach($row as $key => $valuecli)
                    {}
             }
        }
        else{
            $valuecli = $data["customer_id"];
            }
        }
```

Comment: So, what is your question exactly?

Comment: This may be on-topic on Code Review. Please check [if it is on-topic](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to post a good question](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting there.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton In the future please link to the help center when recommending Code Review. Take, `This may be on-topic on Code Review. Please check [if it is on-topic](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to post a good question](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting there.`